# Struts 2 and a simple Facebook API

Tags: java, facebook, struts2

I am trying to make a webapp in java that is capable of posting to a users facebook status, and I am having some problems with the authorization process.  Basically, I have a struts2 action that redirects the user to the facebook login page, which then redirects back to me with a "code".  I then use this code to access another facebook URL (to trade it for an access token).

The problem is, and I'm likely just missing something simple, that this second facebook url doesn't redirect to an action, it instead just returns a page with the access token on it.  So, my question is, how would I access that token to put into my database, preferably without showing the access token to the end user?

TLDR; Any idea how I could call a request from an action in struts2 to an external url and parse the response without showing it to the user?  Thanks!

Cheers,
Lukas Rezek

Comment: are you suing any oauth API? or using simple java code do do this?

Answer (score 3):

So basically you would want 3 pieces:

1. Interceptor
2. authRequest action
3. authResponse action

So the flow is:

1. Interceptor would check if current user has auth token, if not - it will redirect to authRequest action
2. authRequest action will fill up your app details - create url graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=yyy etc
   Please note that redirect_uri is exactly is authResponse action. so after user authorizes your app - browser willo redirect to authResponse action
3. authResponse action is the plave where you retreive the token, save it to DB and probably set it to session. after you done with that - you are done with login and you can redirect to your application home action

Answer (score 0):

To access an external web site within a struts action you have two choices. Create a socket and connect to the external site and send your request via the socket.outputstream and parse the reponse via the socket.inputStream or use a browser emulator such as Apache HttpComponents or HTMLUnit.

I wouldn't let the user of my web-app anywhere near the Facebook site - I would have my own page that asked for the FB login and would handle the interaction with the facebook site using one of the two methods above. I would favour using HTMLUnit as that is designed to look like a browser to the remote site.